# web api private chat message filter asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to create message filter between 2 users. What i mean by filter is that those 2 users will only see their messages and not others just to make it clear.

I have GET method for getting messages like this in my controller where i specify in params from who and to who are those messages. Problem is i dont know how i can pass those 2 params into my method.

I have idea about calling this method from my ChatHub (SignalR) but this clearly isnt best idea so there must be another way how to make it work.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<PrivateChatMessageDTO>> GetPrivateMessages(string fromUserId, string toUserId)
    {
        return await _service.GetPrivateMessages(fromUserId, toUserId);
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this method from the client side?

Comment: I use angularJS with ngResource so i call it with .query() which will call this method under /api/messages route but i figure out that i can use route attribute on this method to solve my problem, but in url i will have later on something like /url/id/id with what i am not rly sure if its good approach